# How to apply tag to Certain Time in Video by using html5

Tags: c#, html, video, tagging, timelapse

Can anybody help me in how to apply tagging on Video according to time lapse.. For example user just click on specific time period on the video and add tag on it. Later on by clicking the tag user redirects to that time frame. It is simple in youtube videos but I want to apply it in Html5 `<video>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

there's nothing baked into the HTML5  element that can do this automagically, but what you can do is when you create a bookmark you would make note of the currentTime attribute and store it as part of the link (eg http://example.com/myvideo.mp4?time=55) then when the user clicks on the link you have your page check to see if there is a time parameter and before playing the video you set currentTime to the appropriate value